# Android: Sensor.getResolution() value

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm working on Android applications which uses SensorManager for different purposes.
During investigation I found that `Sensor.getResolution()` function returns different values for different devices:

**HTC Sensation** has 1.0 resolution value for all on board sensors.

**Motorola XOOM**:

```
3-axis Accelerometer -> 0.009576807  
3-axis Magnetic field sensor -> 0.0625  
L3G4200D Gyroscope sensor -> 0.0012217305  
Linear Acceleration Sensor -> 0.009576807  
Gravity Sensor -> 0.009576807
```

It's not clear whether I need to do additional calculation using this resolution value before using appropriate sensor's values. Official documentation doesn't throw the light upon it.

**Can anybody explain me this 'resolution' value purpose?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of the sensors is voltage. This is converted to an integer by the [ADC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter).

Assume

- the sensitivity of your accelermeter is 800mV/g
- you are measuring between -1.5..1.5 g
- you have a 12 bit ADC

Then your resolution is approximately (1.5g + 1.5g) / 800mV/g = 7*10-4 g / unit.

That is, anything below this cannot be distinguised, hence the name resolution.

**You do not have to do anything with this value. It is just tells you the theoretical limit of the device.** Unfortunately, in my experience, the accuracy of the sensors is worse than this limit... :(

Answer (score 1):

Resolution is defined as smallest change  that can be detected by a sensor.